# How to stop bubbling on the particular element of DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How to stop bubbling on exactly the particula element of the list `ul`?
In my case, it is `<li>` first child element of `ul` which has `data-slide-id` argument I want to pull out?

My JS file:

```
  onSlideClick() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('slider__container')[0].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(e.target)
    })
  }
```

EDIT:
I was trying also:

```
  onSlideClick() {
    this.container[0].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation()
      console.log(e.target)
    })
  }
```

In this scenario, when I click on list ul I get various elements in console like:
`<p>Lorem...... </p>` or `<h3>Lorem.....</h3>`

and I want this function to dig only to:

`<li class="slider__card slider__margin-t--1" data-slide-id="1"> </li>` element.

My index.html:

```
    <ul class="slider__container">
      <!-- 1 slide -->
      <li class="slider__card slider__margin-t--1" data-slide-id="1">
        <div class="slider__card-pic">
          <img >
          <img >
        </div>
        <div class="slider__card-text">
          <h3>Excepteur sint occaecat</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Minus debitis laboriosam ea, magni nulla libero.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- 2 slide -->
      <!-- 3 slide -->
      <!-- 4 slide -->
    </ul>
```

PS. I was trying e.stopPropagation() too.

**EDIT Solution:**

I Found some kind of hack solution, but not ideal... If someone has better idea please let me know:

```
  onSlideClick() {
    console.log(this.container)
    this.container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode && e.target.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName == 'LI') {
        console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode)
      }  
    }) 
  }
```

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()` is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you don't want to stop bubbling, because your code depends on bubbling.
The idea behind your solution is the way to go, but it is not really bullet-proof. You can try to get the parent node until the parent is your `ul`.

Using a while loop :

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.slider__container');
container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  var target = e.target;
  if (target === container)
    return // no need to check further if click happened on the ul
  while (target.parentNode && target.parentNode !== container) {
    target = target.parentNode 
  }
  console.log(target.dataset.slideId);
})
```

```css
ul {
  background-color: blue;
}

li {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slider__container">
  <!-- 1 slide -->
  <li class="slider__card slider__margin-t--1" data-slide-id="1">
    <div class="slider__card-pic">
      <img>
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__card-text">
      <h3>Excepteur sint occaecat</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Minus debitis laboriosam ea, magni nulla libero.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!-- 2 slide -->
  <!-- 3 slide -->
  <!-- 4 slide -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much n00dl3!